# does LEFT JOIN return same row count as left table?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.fk = t2.id;
```

Will it always return the same row count as that of t1 ?

Comment: It should return everything on t1 as well as any matches from t2

Comment: No, It will return all rows from T1 and multiplied row from T2 based on matched key.

Comment: Is there a `UNIQUE` constraint on `t2.id`? Looks like a PK.

Comment: Had there been one, the answer to the question would have been YES. This is the key point :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contract of a left join states that, in the absence of a `WHERE` clause which might remove records from the result set, all records which appear in the left side of the join will appear at least *once*.  Consider the following data set:

```
t1
id | fk
1  | 1
2  | 2

t2
id | value
1  | 1
1  | 2
```

Your query would return this result set:

```
id | fk | id   | value
1  | 1  | 1    | 1
1  | 1  | 1    | 2
2  | 2  | NULL | NULL
```

Note carefully that the first table's `fk = 2` did not match anything to the second table.  This record still appears in the result set, but all columns coming from the second table are `NULL`.  Also, note that `fk = 1` records appear *twice*, because that single record in the first table matched twice to the second table.

Answer (score 2):

If `t2.id` has a unique constraint, the row count will always be the same as if the join isn't there. If it's not unique, you will get multiple duplicates of the same `t1` row, each with its own corresponding `t2` row. Whether that's good enough for you depends on your database design.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(id int, fk int);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1,1);

CREATE TABLE t2(id int, value int);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1,1),(1,2);


SELECT * 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.fk = t2.id;
```

returns 2 rows:

```
id  fk  id  value

1   1   1   1

1   1   1   2
```

Comment: But if t2.id were a PRIMARY KEY, than Yes

Answer (score 1):

> Will it always return the same row count as that of t1?

No.

A `LEFT JOIN` is a join and as such will match one row from one table to multiple rows of another table. The result set may have the same number of rows or more rows.